# Вопрос по клонированию проекта с Github, отсутствуют все пакеты подключенные по умолчанию

Tags: git, asp.net-mvc

Опубликовал свой проект на гитхаб, у меня все работало. При клонировании моего проекта другим человеком проект не запускается, пишет что весь код в ошибках. Причина в отсутствии привязки пакетов NuGet, при ручном восстановлении они добавляются. Как сделать так, чтобы пакеты сразу были привязаны и не надо было их восстанавливать вручную?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, тут два пути:

1. **Не красивый**: добавить установленные у вас локально пакеты в репозиторий. Это называется *vendoring*.  Насколько я знаю, так делают только в Go, так как там нет удобного менеджера пакетов, но и то, в ближайшее время они планируют уйти от этой порочной практики.
2. Добавить в проект файл README.md, в котором человеческим языком описать, что должен сделать человек после клонирования репозитория, чтобы его запустить.  Так делают все и не только в .Net.

Comment: Рекомендую поменять пункты местами. Люди обычно читают сверху вниз :)

Comment: Третий путь; включить автоматическое восстановление пакетов при сборке...